# Dynamic-like alternative for C++ and COM using IDispatch

Tags: c++, com, atl

I was showing a coworker how easily a COM object could be created and used in C++ using the [Microsoft ATL library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9adwcde%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In particular, I wanted to use demonstrate `IDispatch` to show how it can be used to dynamically call a method. However, I don't use C++/ATL frequently enough to not get lost in the templates and convenience methods and classes of ATL.

We created a small COM class, `MyCOMLibrary.SimpleClass` that has a single method named `AppendMessage` that takes 2 `BSTR`s and has no return value.

From a simple Win32 console application, creating and using the COM object was easy:

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> simpleClass;
debugPrint.CoCreateInstance(L"MyCOMLibrary.SimpleClass");
if (simpleClass) {
    CComVariant vModule(L"Demo");
    CComVariant vMessage(L"Welcome to COM");
    simpleClass.Invoke2(L"AppendMessage", &vModule, &vMessage);
}
```

While this makes creating and managing the COM object nearly painless (especially when compared to using `DISPPARAMS`), I was looking for an even more concise way of calling the `AppendMessage` method that reflects modern C++/ATL/COM usage (in VS 2012).

The best case would be like C#'s `dynamic` keyword ([dynamic documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)) (or any other "late-bound" language like JavaScript/VB6/etc):

```
simpleClass.AppendMessage(L"Demo", L"Welcome to COM");
```

Or, without that, this would be more readable:

```
simpleClass.Invoke2(L"AppendMessage", L"Demo", L"Welcome to COM");
```

However, I know the first won't compile as the method doesn't exist on `CComPtr<IDispatch>` and the second won't compile as `Invoke2` requires `VARIANT`s.

I did try using the interface directly as a comparison:

```
// workaround VS2012 intellisense issue with #import
#ifndef __INTELLISENSE__
    #import "progid:MyCOMLibrary.ISimpleClass" version("1.0")
#else
    #include "Debug\MyCOMLibrary.tlh"
#endif

CComPtr<MyCOMLibrary::ISimpleClass> simpleClass;
simpleClass.CoCreateInstance(L"MyCOMLibrary.ISimpleClass");
if (simpleClass) {
    CComBSTR module(L"Interfacing");
    CComBSTR message(L"And, then, there was COM.");
    simpleClass->AppendMessage((BSTR)module, (BSTR)message);
}
```

But, it's nearly identical to the original (and further, I want to do late-bound).

**Question**

Is there a different/shorter/better/awesome way of calling `AppendMethod` using `IDispatch` and ATL that would further impress upon my coworkers that C++ isn't always difficult? (Or, a better way without ATL would also be fine).

Comment: An awesome alternative could be to `#import` the type library and use the interface of interest directly through early binding. I don't think 2012 and even 2010 added anything impressing to ATL for the task in question.

Comment: @RomanR. - I was trying the `#import` option as well (although I did want to use `IDispatch` as part of my demonstration). However `#import` apparently isn't as simple as the documentation implies as there are a few bugs/issues with Intellisense and `#import`

Comment: That's news to me.  Maybe you ought to ask a question about it.

Comment: @HansPassant - I added the details of the `#import` workaround into my question (I found the suggestion for the workaround on MS Connect web site)

Comment: Why don't you use [`CComVariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac97df2h.aspx) together with `Invoke2`?

Comment: @Aschratt -- I did as the code shows. So, I don't understand your comment?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Sorry, I was blinded by the statement *won't compile as `Invoke2` requires `VARIANT`s.*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at VOLE by matthew wilson.

It is at http://vole.sourceforge.net/

It think it does what you want. I have used it before, and it makes IDispatch client programming a breeze.

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19962/Driving-Microsoft-Word-using-VOLE for an example using Microsoft World